# Store same entity in room and distinguish where it was fetched

Tags: android, android-room

I'm practising with room and found the following use case which I don't know how to handle correctly:

In a social network, a user can get posts from various points of the application, for example, a user can get posts from the Home section of the application and the Search section.

Knowing this, I would like to know the best way to store these posts in my database so that, in subsequent entries to the same section, only load the publications from that section.

My first idea was to create a new column in my post entity which stores the section where the post was fetched. However, this idea does not convince me much since it is not scalable and maintainable.

Thanks for reading my question!

Comment: Why do you think it's not scalable or maintainable?

Comment: @JustAnEuropean I think it is not a very scalable/maintainable solution since we are adding an attribute to the post entity strongly related to the view that is consuming it. Although I may be wrong, I am open to hearing opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps consider this demo, pretty scalable (as will be shown)

First the Database stuff.

The table aka `@Entity` annotated class (also must be defined as one of the entities in the `@Database annotation` (aka the list of tables)).

```
@Entity
data class Post(
    @PrimaryKey
    val post_id: Long?=null,
    val post_timestamp: Long= System.currentTimeMillis(),
    val post_text: String,
    val post_user: String,
    val and_so_on: String,
    val post_posted_view: String
)
```

Now the `@Dao` annotated interface (the functions that access the database):-

```
@Dao
interface PostDAO {
    @Insert
    fun insert(post: Post): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_posted_view=:post_posted_view")
    fun getPostsForAView(post_posted_view: String): List<Post>
}
```

- i.e. a fun to insert posts according to the "View"

Now the `@Database` annotated abstract class:-

```
@Database(entities = [Post::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class PostDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getPostDAO(): PostDAO

    companion object {
        private var instance: PostDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): PostDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,PostDatabase::class.java,"postdatabase.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* For brevity of demo */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as PostDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- as a singleton so the one instance is retrieved from wherever being instantiated only the first time it is retrieved.

First a small-scale, just one view (Activity) that allows posts to be made and that also displays the posts (in an edit text for simplicity). So

**MainActivty**:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: PostDatabase
    lateinit var dao: PostDAO
    lateinit var posts: TextView
    lateinit var add_posts: Button
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        posts = this.findViewById(R.id.posts)
        add_posts = this.findViewById(R.id.add_posts)
        add_posts.setOnClickListener {
            addSomePosts(3)
            getPostsForView()
        }
        db = PostDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getPostDAO()
        getPostsForView()
    }

    fun getPostsForView(post_posted_view: String=this.javaClass.name) {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        var afterFirstPost: Boolean=false
        val retrieved_psosts = dao.getPostsForAView(post_posted_view)
        for (post in retrieved_psosts) {
            if (afterFirstPost) {
                sb.append("\n")
            } else {
                sb.append("View Posts for View ${post_posted_view}. There are ${retrieved_psosts.size} posts.\n")
            }
            afterFirstPost = true
            sb.append(post.post_timestamp).append("\t").append(post.post_text)
        }
        posts.setText(sb)
    }

   fun addSomePosts(numberToAdd: Int) {
        for (i in 0..numberToAdd) {
            dao.insert(Post(post_text = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}-i A Post",post_user = "The User", post_posted_view = this.javaClass.name, and_so_on = "blah"))
        }
    }
}
```

**Small-scale Results**

When the App is run then  first nothing much :-

[image]

Click ADD POSTS a few times to mimic some posts (4 per click (even though 3 coded 0-3 = 4)) and then :-

[image]

If the App is run again then immediately (without clicking ADD POSTS) the same is displayed (i.e. the database has persisted and the posts remain).

**Scaling Up**

To scale up, another Activity is added along with Main Activity having a button added to invoke the ***OtherActivity***. So **MainActivity** is now:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: PostDatabase
    lateinit var dao: PostDAO
    lateinit var posts: TextView
    lateinit var add_posts: Button
    lateinit var other_activity: Button /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED */
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        posts = this.findViewById(R.id.posts)
        add_posts = this.findViewById(R.id.add_posts)
        add_posts.setOnClickListener {
            addSomePosts(3)
            getPostsForView()
        }
        other_activity = this.findViewById(R.id.goto_other_activity) /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED */
        /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED >>>>>>>>>>*/
        other_activity.setOnClickListener {
            intent = Intent(this,OtherActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        db = PostDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getPostDAO()
        getPostsForView()
    }

    fun getPostsForView(post_posted_view: String=this.javaClass.name) {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        var afterFirstPost: Boolean=false
        val retrieved_psosts = dao.getPostsForAView(post_posted_view)
        for (post in retrieved_psosts) {
            if (afterFirstPost) {
                sb.append("\n")
            } else {
                sb.append("View Posts for View ${post_posted_view}. There are ${retrieved_psosts.size} posts.\n")
            }
            afterFirstPost = true
            sb.append(post.post_timestamp).append("\t").append(post.post_text)
        }
        posts.setText(sb)
    }

   fun addSomePosts(numberToAdd: Int) {
        for (i in 0..numberToAdd) {
            dao.insert(Post(post_text = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}-i A Post",post_user = "The User", post_posted_view = this.javaClass.name, and_so_on = "blah"))
        }
    }
}
```

The **OtherActivity** code is, bar the layout and class name, identical to the original MainActivity code, it being:-

```
class OtherActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: PostDatabase
    lateinit var dao: PostDAO
    lateinit var posts: TextView
    lateinit var add_posts: Button
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_other)
        posts = this.findViewById(R.id.posts)
        add_posts = this.findViewById(R.id.add_posts)
        add_posts.setOnClickListener {
            addSomePosts(3)
            getPostsForView()
        }
        db = PostDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getPostDAO()
        getPostsForView()
    }

    fun getPostsForView(post_posted_view: String=this.javaClass.name) {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        var afterFirstPost: Boolean=false
        val retrieved_psosts = dao.getPostsForAView(post_posted_view)
        for (post in retrieved_psosts) {
            if (afterFirstPost) {
                sb.append("\n")
            } else {
                sb.append("View Posts for View ${post_posted_view}. There are ${retrieved_psosts.size} posts.\n")
            }
            afterFirstPost = true
            sb.append(post.post_timestamp).append("\t").append(post.post_text)
        }
        posts.setText(sb)
    }

    fun addSomePosts(numberToAdd: Int) {
        for (i in 0..numberToAdd) {
            dao.insert(Post(post_text = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}-i A Post",post_user = "The User", post_posted_view = this.javaClass.name, and_so_on = "blah"))
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing else is changed, i.e. the database is as it was. NO changes at all anywhere in regards to names to be stored. But now if the App is run (restarted not uninstalled and run) then:-

[image]

- Note that for creating the demo the App was actually uninstalled and so the 8 posts are different.

If the Other Activity button is clicked then:-

[image]

- i.e. No posts displayed, as would initially be expected.

However if the ADD POSTS button is clicked a few times (4 to easily spot the difference in the number of posts per view) then:-

[image]

If the back button/icon is clicked, to return to, the MainActivity then:-

[image]

i.e. MainActivity's posts are displayed.

Click Other Activity and again the 16 posts.

The database itself, via App Inspection, should have 8 + 16 = 24 rows:-

[image]

So from what you have described it would be easily scalable. Even say if you had multiple users, then it would simply need the WHERE clause to include selecting the appropriate user.

Now say you wanted to present a list of the "Views" to allow custom selection of views. Then you could base this upon a query, as demonstrated using App Inspection, such as

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I'll give it as the correct answer as it answers my question however, I'm not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this use case.

Comment: @RafaAmo ***Best*** is often opinionated and may be subject to various factors. e.g. the above schema could be considered as not normalised and thus bad practice but the solution to introduce a second table to normalise *(for the post_posted_view column)* could be considered more difficult to introduce, manage and maintain and thus worse from that aspect.